# How to get a specific string and return his css background-color

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to **scrape** a website that contains a "heat map" based in time.

I have a code in python that get de current time and tranform it into a variable.

And I have my code to **scrape** this website.

I am trying to extract the backgound-color of a div tr th based in the current time.

For example, let's suppose it's 19:13 o'clock

I want to return the element **background-color** of the div that contain the string 19:13 and then use this information in another part of my code.

With the code below, I can get all the elements contained in table id 'map-responsive', how is the correct way to get only the info based in my variable current_time_hora

Thanks.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from datetime import datetime
import requests

now = datetime.now()
current_time_hora = now.strftime("%H:%M")
print("Current Time - Hora =", current_time_hora)



headers = requests.utils.default_headers()
headers.update({'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64; rv:79.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/79.0'})
data3 = requests.get('http://www.tradertimerzone.com.br/web/index.php?r=operation%2Fmaps&model=5-15', headers=headers)


if data3.status_code == requests.codes.ok:
    info = BeautifulSoup(data3.text, 'html.parser')
        
    encontraHorarios2 = ((info.findAll('table', {'id': 'map-responsive'})))
    
    
    print(encontraHorarios2)
```

Comment: FYI it’s __scrape__ (and __scraping__, __scraper__, __scraped__) not scrap

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import time

headers = {
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:87.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/87.0",
}

params = {
    "r": "operation/maps",
    "model": "5-15"
}


def main(url, now):
    with requests.Session() as req:
        req.headers.update(headers)
        req.params = params

        req.head(url)
        r = req.get(url)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'lxml')
        target = soup.select_one(
            f'th:-soup-contains("{now}")')['style']
        print(target)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    now = time.strftime('%H:%M')
    print(f"Current Time: {now}")
    main('http://www.tradertimerzone.com.br/web/index.php', now)
```

Output:

```
Current Time: 01:42
;background:#00B050
```